# Help with unknown car name

Tags: vehicle-identification

I've tried a lot but I couldn't get a clue, this is the only picture I could get.

The seller mentioned it was a 60's "dihatsu", but I couldn't get to be sure.
Also I need help with its body tuning ideas, and how easy would it be to get it to look like a 70's ford mustang ?

[image: car's only available picture]

Comment: need picture from front and back also, ask the seller for them.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We really need you to focus on a question here. The way you have it, it's **very** broad, meaning, there's way too much to answer. Can you pick a starting place and rewrite your question, then ask subsequent questions building upon the first?

Comment: Daihatsu does not appear to have [ever made a vehicle that looks like this](http://www.automobile-catalog.com/timeline-daihatsu.html#1951), certainly not in the 60's. So if it's truly a Daihatsu, it's been heavily modified - I mean, *maybe* it's a '69 Consorte with a modified rear-end, although I can't tell from the picture. You'll have to ask the seller. As for "how easy would it be to get it to look like a Mustang"... not really sure what kind of answer you're looking for to "how easy". Anywhere from "no problem" to "impossible" based on your motivation, creativity, skill set, and tools.

Comment: @JasonC thank you , it's very unlikely to be modified .

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 , What is this car's name ?

Comment: @Moab i'm trying

Comment: @MohamedIslamFares Then it's definitely not a Daihatsu. But that Datsun in the answer is pretty darn similar looking, and it's a pretty unique looking vehicle. Plus "Datsun" and "Daihatsu" are similar enough in spelling that a mistake along the line somewhere seems totally conceivable.

Comment: I'd walk away from the purchase. If nobody on here can accurately name the car, then you're likely not going to be able to find parts for it easily. And it looks like it'll need a lot of parts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at images, if I had to guess, I'd suggest you are looking at a 1974-ish 120Y (or B210 in the States) coupe. The one in this picture is from Australia, or at least that's what it says on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissan_Sunny#Export_markets).

[image]

Comment: You think it's a Datsun? It does have a similar window layout, although the front bumper is a bit off, so is the keyhole relative to the door handle. Closest guess so far though. I couldn't find any similar looking Daihatsus or Toyotas from the era.

Comment: @JasonC - Look at the body line over the wheel arches and down the bottom. Then look at the back glass and the c-pillar angle. Look at how the wheels look in the arches. Look at the top and the angle of the back. And if you look at the lock location, it's spot on ... the angle of the photos throws it off. I'd give it about a 95% probability this is the car in the picture.

Comment: Yeah; I see. I'd give it 95% too. Or maybe a [3rd gen Sunny Coupe](http://www.automobile-catalog.com/timeline-datsun.html), part of that same series (early - mid '70s). I'm still suspicious of that front bumper. Can't explain the doors; the keyhole is below the ridge in the OP's pic. And there's no curve in that rear window corner. Maybe it's some kind of slight variant that you don't see in common internet pics, or had some work done unknown to the seller. +1 way better than what I found.

Comment: @JasonC - The front bumper doesn't look stock to me. Also, take into account the car in the OP's question is beat to crap, whereas the one in my picture is nearly pristine. The grill on the C-pillar is gone. There's no vinyl top on it, and there isn't enough detail in the OP pic to make out the body line which you can see in my picture (center of door panel you talk about).

Comment: @JasonC - I see what you're saying about the lock, now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Ah, yeah, lack of grill totally makes the difference in that rear pillar make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can find is a 1973 Toyota Liftback 2000 GT. But I don't think it is. Maybe there are other manufacturers around the same time building similar cars?

[image]